# Traefik in the Docker Compose to enable access into the local (Drupal) website development environment from an external device (e.g. mobile)

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, dns, traefik

I have local Drupal web development environment based on Docker Compose on Mac.

The `labels` section in the Nginx container in the `docker-compose.yml` file take care of accessing the local website from localhost via Traefik:

```
labels:
  - 'traefik.backend=nginx'
  - 'traefik.port=80'
  - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:local.developedwebsite.com'
  - 'traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https'
```

The `etc/hosts` file takes care of DNS:

```
127.0.0.1 local.developedwebsite.com
```

And finally the `traefik.toml` takes care of rewriting from 'http://' into 'https://'

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
            entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

All works well if I want to access the website via `https://local.developedwebsite.com`.

But I also need to access the local website from an another device on the local network (e.g. mobile phone/tablet) for accessibility testing. Because I cannot change Router DNS, the connection can be done only via IP, and there lies a problem: Drupal expects it is accessed from a single domain name. The simple solution to add my local IP into Traefik like this `'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:local.developedwebsite.com, MY.LOCAL.IP.ADDRESS'` won't work. It will indeed reach the Nginx, but the Drupal itself won't work properly.

Is there any way I can set-up Traefik to rewrite **frontend IP address** into **backend domain name** on the fly?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a dns set up in place for such testings.  Purchase a small router where you are the admin of the network and set up a local dns.  Or, use XCode simulator to set up an Iphone in the Mac